# Change column names of many data frames in a for-loop

Tags: r, variables, assign

I have a bunch of data frames generated by:

```
for(i in 1:100){
    assign(paste("df", i, sep=""), data.frame(1,2))
}
```

I want to rename the first column of all of these 100 data frames to be `Column1`. (Note that in my real data each first column is unique, unlike the example here, where they are each `X1`.)  This will be the same for all data frames.

For any individual one, I can do this.  For example:

```
names(df45)[1]<-"Column1"
```

However, I am running into problems when attempting to automate the process.  Here is the (wrong) code I have tried:

```
names(eval(parse(text=paste("df", i, sep=""))))[1] <- "Column1"
```

How should I modify this?  And is there a quicker way to access variables in loops that this?

I have come across other answers that say it is better to put these things in a list and process it like this:

```
#put into a list
l.df <- lapply(ls(pattern="df[0-9]+"), function(x) get(x))

for(i in 1:100){
    names(l.df[[i]])[1] <- "Column1"
}
```

However, I want to be able to merge all the data frames together as follows:

```
df <- merge(df1, df2, df3, df4, ....... df100, by="Column1")
```

Comment: Please put the dataframes in a list instead of creating them as separate, named objects. This makes both the renaming of the columns and the `merge` operation infinitely easier (because the same code will work regardless of the number of dataframes).

Comment: @baptiste, assume I have gotten the column names all changed to `Column1`. I can't quite figure out the `do.call` part.  I have tried this: `do.call("merge", c(l.df, by="Column1"))`.

Comment: that would have worked if merge allowed more than 2 data.frames as arguments. Here you could use `Reduce(function(x,y)merge(x,y,by="Column1"), l.df)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, I would work on a list (of data.frames). You can use lapply to "climb" each list element. I'm borrowing the merge approach from @baptiste (posted in comments).

```
xy <- replicate(10, data.frame(a = 1:10, b = runif(10)), simplify = FALSE)
xy <- lapply(xy, function(x) {names(x)[1] <- "Golum1"; x})
Reduce(function(x,y) merge(x,y,by="Golum1"), xy)

   Golum1          b.x        b.y        b.x        b.y       b.x        b.y       b.x       b.y        b.x        b.y
1       1 0.0002497286 0.44790338 0.12656118 0.85306085 0.9502253 0.92816557 0.6727456 0.3615492 0.71520420 0.26933313
2       2 0.1416911036 0.56330792 0.03834924 0.95777112 0.4763716 0.28533075 0.8729803 0.7035205 0.49824660 0.15685903
3       3 0.3454216446 0.42778131 0.35065726 0.35513107 0.6610847 0.21600874 0.9611296 0.2527102 0.62142047 0.32401890
4       4 0.2128049061 0.20300980 0.35529195 0.19681124 0.6105881 0.85292309 0.3311055 0.4953804 0.05079081 0.98322541
5       5 0.5967234119 0.93926727 0.74456886 0.25971581 0.3739592 0.01498909 0.2683361 0.9895955 0.45829244 0.76854781
6       6 0.4843087369 0.04535037 0.29100912 0.05801034 0.1010084 0.31980135 0.7572697 0.6022717 0.86408382 0.10516840
7       7 0.0624480459 0.58510411 0.62256365 0.97236759 0.6910560 0.21823825 0.8169870 0.3162987 0.79414611 0.43907780
8       8 0.1764713391 0.05768646 0.30316764 0.25180931 0.9378119 0.06416274 0.6814944 0.9889381 0.13944101 0.51939788
9       9 0.9533833019 0.70950657 0.04435285 0.92314396 0.4208451 0.34137729 0.8876309 0.9789025 0.43711122 0.71978702
10     10 0.7814107563 0.93566272 0.76036172 0.71139862 0.5308587 0.19734855 0.8359664 0.6903358 0.22433803 0.09343658

# warnings are due to name collisions
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this works for you

```
 for(i in 1:100){
  assign(paste("df", i, sep=""), data.frame(1,2))
}

require(naturalsort)
data<-do.call(rbind,sapply(ls(pattern="df[0-9]+"),function(x) get(x),simplify = F))
data<-data[naturalorder(rownames(data)),]

colnames(data)[1] <-'Column1'

head(data)
```